# dynamic_reconfigure parameters not known until runtime. How?

Tags: ros, camera-drivers, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As I understand it, the dynamic_reconfigure requires a .cfg file to specify the parameters that will be used (and I've used this successfully, both C and python).

I'm working on a GenICam camera driver, and can't know which parameters the camera supports until runtime.  Hence I can't make a .cfg file since I don't know what the parameters will be.  Is there a way to use dynamic_reconfigure, but to set up the parameter specs after we've queried the camera?  Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57167/dynamic_reconfigure-parameters-not-known-until-runtime.--how?/) by [ssafarik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1687/ssafarik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 306 on 2013-03-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually, some dynamic reconfigure improvements did land into Groovy thanks to Ben Ballard.  However, without a clear maintainer, these were not documented.

Here's an example usage of updating the limits at runtime:
https://github.com/ros-drivers/urg_node/blob/groovy-devel/src/urg_node.cpp#L78

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2013-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0